# bind select list and input text box together

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

How to bind the value of select list and input box together.

```
<label class="control-label">Select city</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="cityName" ng-model="City">
                    <option  value="delhi">Delhi</option>
                    <option  value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                    <option  value="banglore">Banglore</option>
                    <option  value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <div ng-if="city === 'Other'">
                    <label class="control-label">Specify city</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="city" >
                </div>
            </br>
```

Value entered inside text input should be available to controller with the same model as of select list. How to achieve this functionality.

Comment: What you got, if you entered inside `delhi`  the textbox?

Comment: Other is written in the text box when it opens. if i try to edit the input box then it gets hide

Comment: Yes, because you did the condition `ng-if="city === 'Other'` . So it's going correct

Comment: yes but i want to get the unspecified city from the input text box. Then how to achieve this

Comment: Remove the `ng-if` condition

Comment: But the input box should be shown only when user select other option. After that the value of specified city should go the the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not achieve that with same model name. Because, if you change any text in textbox, ng-if condition will be false and as a result, your textbox will hide. Instead try to assign different model(For Ex. cityOther) to textbox, and when you post that data from controller, check for city value in model. If city value is "Other", then assign the value of cityOther to city. In that way, you will be able to accomplish the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Ankit
I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what I think is are expecting. FYI OTHER is at the bottom of the select option.
On a different note, if you want to apply this to many components across, better make this into a directive.
Also check on [ui-validate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate) it comes handy when validation has prerequisites dependencies check on other properties other than the binded.

```js
(function (angular) {
 'use strict';
 angular
  .module('wierdSelectApp', [])
  .controller('demoController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

   /* constant to hold other city value, easy to do checks... */
   var OTHER_CITY = 'Other'
   /* cities fo user to select from.... */
   var cities = ['Mumbai',
    'Delhi',
    'Bengaluru',
    'Hyderabad',
    'Ahmedabad',
    'Chennai',
    'Kolkata',
    'Surat',
    'Pune',
    'Jaipur',
    'Lucknow',
    'Kanpur',
    'Nagpur',
    'Visakhapatnam',
    'Indore',
    'Thane',
    'Bhopal',
    'Patna',
    'Vadodara',
    'Ghaziabad',
    'Ludhiana',
    'Coimbatore',
    'Agra',
    OTHER_CITY];

   /* function to create the model to hold selected/specified city*/ 
   function createSelectionModel() {
    var obj = {
     selectedCity: null, // hold the selected city
     specifiedCity: null // hold the specified city
    };

    /* 
     returns the city user has selected or specified. 
     if the user has select a city from the drop-down other than OTHER, then
     the selected value will be returned. 
     else if OTHER was selected, the user specified city will returned.
    */
    obj.__defineGetter__("value", function () {
     return (!!this.selectedCity && this.selectedCity === OTHER_CITY) ? this.specifiedCity : this.selectedCity;
    });

    return obj;
   }

   /* attach cities and selection model to scope...  */
   function onLoad() {
    $scope.cities = cities;
    $scope.selection = createSelectionModel();
    $scope.OTHER_CITY = OTHER_CITY;
   }

   onLoad();

  }
  ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="wierdSelectApp">
    <div ng-controller="demoController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <!-- dropdown select -->
            <div>
                <label for="selectedCity">Select city</label>
                <select name="selectedCity" ng-model="selection.selectedCity" ng-options="opt for opt in cities"></select>
            </div>

            <!-- other city to specify -->
            <div ng-if="!!selection.selectedCity && selection.selectedCity === OTHER_CITY">
                <label class="control-label">Specify city</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selection.specifiedCity" />
            </div>

            <hr />
            <!-- display selected value-->
            <div>Answer : {{selection.value}}</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```